# trouble with memory

Tags: debugging, memory, process, pthreads, fork

I have very long code, with multiple processes, and somewhere in the program while it is running I get a message like "invalid next size (fast)" and some numbers that make no sense.

I can't get gdb to run in that process alone, and I cannot figure out where in the program this is happening. I put `printf`s left and right (I flush it with `fflush` as well so it will print out exactly at that time) but still I can't find the exact line when this is happening!

How should a problem like this be debugged? I would appreciate the help because I have tried everything that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

First try to find the line with

```
grep -rni "invalid next" *.c
```

assuming it's all c files in some subdirectories. Then you should see what these numbers mean (or correct the error message to be more meaningful). If you don't have gnu-grep:

```
find -name '*.c' | xargs grep -ni "invalid next"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like many people have this problem when they are using the sizeof() function to allocate the wrong amount of memory for something.

Check out these threads:

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=4819

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/free-invalid-next-size-fast-c-error-729852/